# suddenly displays file names with red ground

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I just created simple project to display "Hello World". And It was working and i was going through features in configuration. suddenly it gives unexpected output. It displays some of the file names in red back ground. I am attaching screenshot

[image]

Let me know if you know/guess the reason behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to system/configuration select main store. Then go to developer and set "No" in template path hints. By mistake i changed it to yes. By setting it to "NO" i solved my problem.